# Can I use AutoMapper for element type to list<type>

Tags: list, automapper

Is this a valid mapping configuration

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PriceSummaryRequest, List<Route>>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<RouteResolver>());
```

I am getting object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Comment: can you provide some more code (the `RoutResolver` would be nice)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ConvertUsing method instead:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PriceSummaryRequest, List<Route>>().ConvertUsing<RouteConverter>();
```

You'll need to change the RouteResolver to be an ITypeConverter, but that's pretty straightforward.

ConvertUsing is used to convert between one type and another,